# How do "Inverter" or "IGBT" welders control CC and CV output?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, control, constant-current, power-consumption

I have a question on welding units. A lot of the newer units these days have "Dependable Fairchild or Infineon IGBT (non module)", "MOSFET design for Hobby use" and I can't tell if all of this stuff is just BS that PR is feeding out or if theses units do use MOSFETs, IGBTs,  and Inverters. On Everlast Generator's site, it says stuff like this:

"Because Inverters output power is electronically regulated, you have a wide power adjustment range from nil - 100% enabling you to fine tune them to your specific needs. For instance, with regard to MIG welders sometimes setting 2 may mean inadequate power and setting 3 may be excessive. It is here that inverter welder helps."

Which adds to my confusion. I have tried find schematics on the internet but only have found these:
http://www.irf.com/technical-info/appnotes/an-1045b.pdf

https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-9742.pdf

http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Welding-Machines-Converters-Using-TRENCHSTOP5+-+ART-v1.0-en.pdf?fileId=5546d46147a9c2e40147ce6f0a197daf

http://danyk.cz/svar_en.html

All of these add to how they work but not how they are controlled. Any information would be great.

Comment: They would be controlled with feedback I imagine. Most likely, output current and voltage are monitored and fed to a micro-controller which implements CC or CV or CC/CV control. For DC, CC or CV is pretty easy. Can be managed cycle by cycle. Don't know if welders do AC, but for AC output, you would need to compare the output current or voltage to an internal model of a time varying waveform rather than a static value.

Comment: They are PWM controlled all of them, you have the schematics and description in that links, where is te question?

Answer (score 1):

The comment by mkeith and Marko Bursic provide the basic answer. PWM control signals for the switching devices can be generated by Arduino type micro controllers with associated interface boards. An isolated current sensor and voltage sensor is also required. You should be able to find reference material that describes PWM voltage and current control methods including current limited voltage control and voltage limited current control. Look for both basic material about PWM current and voltage control and for PWM control as applied to welding. You will find a lot of material about PWM control for motors, heaters, lights and battery chargers. That might be of use, but there are probably specific requirements for welding.

Comment: Arduino is not a type. ATmega is a type.

Comment: @Charles Cowie, Would you share a link to something to point me in the right zone. I keep find stuff on like 10A, not 200A...

Comment: I don't have any links to suggest. The control design will not differ very much from low current to high current. Higher current switching devices will require higher driver current. You can probably find a suitable isolated driver board that will be suitable. The current sensor and feedback signal conditioning device needs to be suitable for the higher current. You might want to look for some general tutorial information on power electronics.